# How do I populate array of ids using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to populate array of object IDS but it doesn't work

Mongoose Object

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  products: [{
    product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
    quantity: { type: Number, default: 1},
    price: { type: Number, default: 0},
  }],
});

let Model = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
module.exports = Model;
```

The API route for getting all the orders

```
const Order = require('../models/order');

router.get('/orders', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {

    Order
    .find({ owner: req.decoded.user._id })
    .populate('products.product')
    .exec((err, orders) => {
      res.json({
        orders: orders
      });
    });
  })
```

It still showing the ID of the product

```
"products": [
                {
                    "_id": "5a47b6c35e96e3900fd63984",
                    "price": 0,
                    "quantity": 2
                }
            ]
```

Comment: please share the product model initialisation

Comment: Look at the updated version

Comment: I mean't `let productModel = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);`. The statement should contain the same identifier string in the `OrderSchema`. Do these match in your case?

Comment: It is. I show you the result already, meaning it is working, it is just how to populate, that I have no idea.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @DaveHowson I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
```

with

```
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
```